# MS Access VBA Replace Specif range in a string

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace

I am trying to get rid of "40-S8-7710" Within the string without specifically giving the replace function "40-S8-7710" due to the fact there will be other strings that may contain "50-S2-7710", "11-42-7710" etc..
The code below removes "40-S8-7710" but it also removes everything after.
I am wanting to return "10-7190 20-2071 30-2061 S1-AOUT04X188"

Any Ideas?

```
Dim NewString As String
Set NewString = "10-7190 20-2071 30-2061 40-S8-7710 S1-AOUT04X188"

NewString = Replace(NewString , Mid(NewString , InStr(NewString , "7710") - 6), "")
MsgBox(NewString)
```

Comment: Huh. Why not simply `Replace(NewString, "40-S8-7710 ", "")` ?

Comment: I am not wanting to specify Replace(NewString, "40-S8-7710 ", "", because if I get another NewString that equals "10-7190 20-2071 30-2061 45-D2-7710 S1-AOUT04X188" I would want to remove "7710" and the 6 charactes to the left. NewString in my function will always change the 6 characters to the left of "7710". So i am wanting to remove "7710" and the 6 character to left of it since the 6 character to left of "7710" will always be changing

Comment: You do not need `Set` to assign a value to `NewString`. Just do `NewString = "10-7190 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how perform the action i was looking for by doing this

```
NewString= (Replace(NewString, (Mid(NewString, (InStr(NewString, "7710") - 7), 11)), ""))
```

This would return "10-7190 20-2071 30-2067 S1-AOUT04X188"...... "7710" is the only unique number I could use to pull since the 6 characters to the left of "7710" could be different depending what a user enters. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Left([string],24)+Right([string],13)